# Does GraphDB Reason over Namespaced Terms?

Tags: rdf, graph-databases, graphdb, triplestore

If I define terms in my RDF namespace, for example dcterms, will GraphDB resolve the ontology and perform reasoning over it? By 'resolve' the ontology I mean fetch the OWL representation at the URI and take the rules into consideration. I understand that forward chaining is being used to reason, so I imagine that if this were happening-the ontologies would be resolved on data insertion.

What has lead me to believe this might be possible is the following bit from the JSON-LD specification,

```
When processing JSON-LD documents, links to remote contexts are 
typically followed automatically, resulting in the transfer of files
without the explicit request of the user for each one.
```

Comment: You'll have to clarify your question a bit. For one thing, what do you mean when you say "resolve the ontology"? What, exactly, are you expecting GraphDB to do? Try and be specific, perhaps show some sample data and describe what you expect to happen.

Comment: I'm pretty sure the question is whether GraphDB will consider all ontologies resp. their axioms used in a dataset - **this is clearly not the case** without loading them explicitly. So, if you're using external ontologies like DC-Terms, FOAF, SKOS, DBpedia, etc, you always have to load those datasets as well for making it available to the reasoning engine. No forward chaining engine does Linked Data retrieval when applying the rules - the URIs are just identifiers, but the semantics behind each namespace is clearly opaque. Solving this is trivial, just collect all used ontologies and load them

Comment: @UninformedUser I'd rather not _guess_ about the intent of the OP, but prefer that _they_ clarify what they're actually after.

Comment: I've added a bit to the question to clarify that what I meant was... The reasoner visits the URI and, assuming that it's a valid OWL file, will take its logic into account while inserting new triples. So being told that they're opaque should answer the question (someone can post an official answer or I'll answer it with an example).